# outputting checkbox ids to an empty div

Tags: checkbox

I am currently building a keyword bank to assist in tagging my in-house design assets. My idea is to have each keyword as a checkbox form element with one empty div at the bottom. You'd go through the entire list, check what you need and the text assigned to the id of that checkbox would populate in the empty div, separated by commas, and I can just copy/paste that text right into the metadata.  I plan on having hundreds, so I'm hoping there is simple solution to this.

I have no problem setting up the html form/checkboxes, but I am unsure how to make this text populate in that empty div—or even IF it's possible. Would I use jQuery? Ajax? I also don't need a submit button—just that div to update immediately each time a checkbox is touched. Would I also need to have some server-side communication with a submit button to even make this work?

Thank you so much in advance for any help you can give or any direction you can point me in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cexbvqe9/)

What you need is basically something like this :

```
$( ":checkbox" ).click(function() {
       //alert($( this ).val());
        $("#myText").append($(this).val() + ";");    
});
```

You can forget the alert. This will add the value assigned to the checkbox in the div followed with a coma. :)

Comment: I seriously cannot thank you enough! This works so well! I do have one more question—is there a way to remove the value in the div if someone changes their mind and unchecks the box? I assume just duplicating the code and changing 'append' to something else?

Comment: Yeah I guess you could check if the checkbox is checked and do something like a `$("#myText").replace($(this).val(),"")` if he's being unchecked